# gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1' when cross-compiling

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, linux-kernel, arm

I downloaded toolchain from parrot Github, installed, now I am trying to crosscompile here with the following command line:

```
hp@hp-desktop:~/swing-opensource-master/sources/linux-2.6.36/linux-2.6.36$ make ARCH=arm zImage CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/
```

here's the error log:

```
hp@hp-desktop:~/swing-opensource-master/sources/linux-2.6.36/linux-2.6.36$ make ARCH=arm zImage CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: "include/generated/mach-types.h" è aggiornato.
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
/home/hp/swing-opensource-master/sources/linux-2.6.36/linux-2.6.36/./Kbuild:35: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "kernel/bounds.s" non riuscito
make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Errore 1
Makefile:934: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "prepare0" non riuscito
make: *** [prepare0] Errore 2
```

Comment: How about `CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/arm-2012.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-`?

Comment: Worked thanks. Thumb up forum you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-`-prefixed toolchain in `bin` instead. e.g.

```
CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/arm-2012.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
```

instead of

```
CROSS_COMPILE= CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/
```